# Prove existence/non-existence of a pdf given mean, std, range

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given:
Mean = 100,
Range = [4, 10000],
std = 3000

Is it possible to prove whether a pdf exists or not that satisfies these values? If it does exist, what would be approximate shape of the distribution?

Answer (score 1):

The standard deviation looks suspiciously high.  Let's see: the
largest standard deviation for a given mean and range should
be when all the mass is at the extremes of the range.  If you put mass $m$ at $4$ and $1-m$ at $10000$, to have mean $100$ you need $m = 825/833$, and then
the standard deviation is $\sqrt{825/833 (4^2) + 8/833 (10000^2) - 100^2} \approx 974.8846$.  So the answer is that there is no such pdf.

Comment: Elegant answer. The 2nd term in std expression should be 8/833.